# Can not create Dynamic Link URL Prefix for subdomain

Tags: firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a domain registered with Google domains. Call it 'example.com'. The apex and www both point to Firebase hosting.
I want to create a Dynamic Link for app.example.com. However, when I go to "Add URL Prefix" in the Firebase console and enter my app.example.com, I get the error

> It looks like you already have content served on this path. Specify a different path prefix to avoid conflicts with existing content.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np9fI.png)

But I am not serving any content on that subdomain. It won't even load if you open it in the browser, obviously because there is no DNS record set for the subdomain.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Some more context:

- it does work if I add a path prefix. But I don't want a path prefix.
- there are no other dynamic links set up for this project
- there are no other dynamic links set up for this domain or any of its subdomains
- the domain is added to the authorized domains (both apex and app subdomain)

note: Just to be entirely clear - I am not using "example.com" in the Firebase console - that is just a placeholder in this post.